# How to set norelativenumber on CmdlineEnter and relativenumber on CmdlineLeave?

Tags: neovim

I am trying to set `norelativenumber` on `CmdlineEnter` and `relativenumber` on `CmdlineLeave`, but it didn't work. Why is that?

```lua
local setup = function()
  vim.api.nvim_exec([[
  augroup SmartNumberGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineEnter * set norelativenumber
  autocmd CmdlineLeave * set relativenumber
  augroup END]], true)
end

return {
  setup = setup
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `redraw` after setting `relativenumber` with the `CmdLineEnter` event:

```
augroup SmartNumberGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdLineEnter * set norelativenumber|redraw
    autocmd CmdLineLeave * set relativenumber
augroup END
```

I didn't do it in lua but it should work the same. Also note that you probably want to have this behavior happening only when you start a command with `:` but `CmdLineEnter` is also triggered by `/` or `?`. So you might want to have this as your `autocmd`:

```
autocmd CmdLineEnter * if (v:event.cmdtype == ':') | set norelativenumber | redraw | endif
```

Comment: `CmdLineEnter : ` should work I think

Comment: Awesome!!!! But why I don't need to use `redraw` after `relativenumber`?

Comment: You don’t need `redraw` after `CmdLineLeave` because that puts you in normal mode which already redraws the screen.

Comment: Thanks @Christian good point